# Conditional expectation and variance with coin flips

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let $N$ be a random number chosen uniformly at random from the set {${1, 2, 3, 4}$}. Given that $N = n$, coin A is flipped n times and coin B is flipped $(5 − n)$ times.

What is $Var(X)$?

Comment: Everything looks good to me except $E(X^2)$. Remember $E(X^2)=\sum_{x=0}^5 x^2 p_X(x)$

Comment: Is X a conditional random variable or a unconditional random variable?

Comment: What even *is* $X$?  ---  Oh, I see.  a large amount of explanatory text has been edited out of the question.  Don't do that.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text you have removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything looks good except for $\mathsf E(X^2)$

We have

$$\mathsf P(X=0\mid N=1)=0.3\cdot0.5^4$$
$$\mathsf P(X=0\mid N=2)=0.3^2\cdot0.5^3$$
$$\mathsf P(X=0\mid N=3)=0.3^3\cdot 0.5^2$$
$$\mathsf P(X=0\mid N=4)=0.3^4\cdot0.5$$
$$\mathsf P(X=1\mid N=1)=0.7\cdot0.5^4+0.3\cdot{4\choose 1}\cdot0.5^4$$
$$\mathsf P(X=1\mid N=2)={2\choose 1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3\cdot0.5^3+0.3^2\cdot{3\choose 1}\cdot0.5^3$$
$$\mathsf P(X=1\mid N=3) ={3\choose 1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3^2\cdot0.5^2+0.3^3\cdot{2\choose 1}\cdot0.5^2$$
$$\mathsf P(X=1\mid N=4)={4\choose 1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3^3\cdot0.5+0.3^4\cdot0.5$$
$$\mathsf P(X=2\mid N=1)=0.7\cdot{4\choose 1}\cdot0.5^4+0.3\cdot{4\choose2}\cdot0.5^4$$
$$\mathsf P(X=2\mid N=2)=0.7^2\cdot0.5^3+0.3^2\cdot{3\choose2}\cdot0.5^3+{2\choose1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3\cdot{3\choose1}\cdot0.5^3$$
$$\mathsf P(X=2\mid N=3)={3\choose2}\cdot0.7^2\cdot0.3\cdot0.5^2+0.3^3\cdot0.5^2+{3\choose1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3^2\cdot{2\choose1}\cdot0.5^2$$
$$\mathsf P(X=2\mid N=4)={4\choose2}\cdot0.7^2\cdot0.3^2\cdot0.5+{4\choose1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3^3\cdot0.5$$
$$\mathsf P(X=3\mid N=1)=0.7\cdot{4\choose2}\cdot0.5^4+0.3\cdot{4\choose3}\cdot0.5^4$$
$$\mathsf P(X=3\mid N=2)=0.7^2\cdot{3\choose1}\cdot0.5^3+{2\choose1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3\cdot{3\choose2}\cdot0.5^3+0.3^2\cdot0.5^3$$
$$\mathsf P(X=3\mid N=3)=0.7^3\cdot0.5^2+{3\choose2}\cdot0.7^2\cdot0.3\cdot{2\choose1}\cdot0.5^2+{3\choose1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3^2\cdot0.5^2$$
$$\mathsf P(X=3\mid N=4)={4\choose3}\cdot0.7^3\cdot0.3\cdot0.5+{4\choose2}\cdot0.7^2\cdot0.3^2\cdot0.5$$
$$\mathsf P(X=4\mid N=1)=0.7\cdot{4\choose3}\cdot0.5^4+0.3\cdot0.5^4$$
$$\mathsf P(X=4\mid N=2)=0.7^2\cdot{3\choose2}\cdot0.5^3+{2\choose1}\cdot0.7\cdot0.3\cdot0.5^3$$
$$\mathsf P(X=4\mid N=3)=0.7^3\cdot{2\choose1}\cdot0.5^2+{3\choose2}\cdot0.7^2\cdot0.3\cdot0.5^2$$
$$\mathsf P(X=4\mid N=4)=0.7^4\cdot0.5+{4\choose3}\cdot0.7^3\cdot0.3\cdot0.5$$
$$\mathsf P(X=5\mid N=1)=0.7\cdot0.5^4$$
$$\mathsf P(X=5\mid N=2)=0.7^2\cdot0.5^3$$
$$\mathsf P(X=5\mid N=3)=0.7^3\cdot0.5^2$$
$$\mathsf P(X=5\mid N=4)=0.7^4\cdot0.5$$

Hence

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf E(X^2)
&=0^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\left(\mathsf P(X=0\mid N=1)+\cdots +\mathsf P(X=0\mid N=4)\right)\\\\
&+1^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\left(\mathsf P(X=1\mid N=1)+\cdots +\mathsf P(X=1\mid N=4)\right)\\\\
&+2^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\left(\mathsf P(X=2\mid N=1)+\cdots +\mathsf P(X=2\mid N=4)\right)\\\\
&+3^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\left(\mathsf P(X=3\mid N=1)+\cdots +\mathsf P(X=3\mid N=4)\right)\\\\
&+4^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\left(\mathsf P(X=4\mid N=1)+\cdots +\mathsf P(X=4\mid N=4)\right)\\\\
&+5^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\left(\mathsf P(X=5\mid N=1)+\cdots +\mathsf P(X=5\mid N=4)\right)\\\\
&=0^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot0.0408\\\\
&+1^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot0.3076\\\\
&+2^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot0.9216\\\\
&+3^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot1.3816\\\\
&+4^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot1.0376\\\\
&+5^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot0.3108\\\\
&=10.2
\end{align*}$$

Then

$$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2=10.2-3^2=1.2$$

As a check, the respective probabilities sum to $1$ since we have

$$\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(0.0408+0.3076+0.9216+1.3816+1.0376+0.3108\right)=1$$
*exhales*

Note: This needs to be checked

Comment: Not really checked, but found the same answer for variance of $X$. So time to inhale again :-).

Comment: Did you simulate it or solve it analytically? I wasn't sure if this was the most efficient method.

Comment: I did not simulate but gave an answer myself.

Comment: Whoops I didn't see that. Your answer is much more efficient [+1]!

Answer (score 1):

It is not unthinkable that this answer uses techniques that are not (yet) at your disposal, but makes clear that the answer of Remy is correct and that less calculations are needed to achieve this result.

First fix $n\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then we can write $X=A_1+\cdots+A_n+B_1+\cdots+B_{5-n}$ where the RHS is a summation of independent Bernoulli distributed random variable. The $A_i$ with parameter $0.7$ and the $B_i$ with parameter $0.5$.

Based on that we find:

$$\mathbb E[X\mid N=n]=n\times0.7+(5-n)\times0.5=2.5+n\times0.2$$

and:
$$\mathsf{Var}(X\mid N=n)=n\times0.7\times0.3+(5-n)\times0.5\times0.5=1.25-n\times0.04$$

This implies that: $$\mathbb E[X\mid N]=2.5+N\times0.2$$and:$$\mathsf{Var}(X\mid N)=1.25-N\times0.04$$

A general rule states that:$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid N]]\tag1$$

and another general rule states that: $$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[\mathsf{Var}(X\mid N)]+\mathsf{Var}(\mathbb E[X\mid N])\tag2$$

Working out $(1)$ we get: $$\mathbb EX=2.5+\mathbb EN\times0.2=2.5+2.5\times0.2=3$$Working out $(2)$ we get:$$\mathsf{Var}X=[1.25-2.5\times0.04]+0.04\mathsf{Var}N=1.15+0.04\times1,25=1.15+0.05=1.2$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is correct, though you should explicitly mention that you are assuming $P(A)=0.5$.
In this case,
\begin{multline*}
P(A\mid HH)=\frac{P(HH\mid A)P(A)}{P(HH)}=\frac{P(HH\mid A)P(A)}{P(HH\mid A)P(A)+P(HH\mid B)P(B)}\\
=\frac{\binom{3}{2}0.7^{2}\cdot0.3\cdot0.5}{\binom{3}{2}0.7^{2}\cdot0.3\cdot0.5+\binom{3}{2}0.5^{2}\cdot0.3\cdot0.5}=\frac{147}{272}\approx0.54.
\end{multline*}

Your expectation computation looks correct, but your variance does not.
Remember,
$$
\text{Var}(X)=E\left[\left(X-E(X)\right)^{2}\right]=E[X^{2}]-(E\left[X\right])^{2}.
$$
You already know $E[X]$, so all you have to do to is compute $E[X^{2}]$.

**Hint:** Order of operations matters.

Comment: For the first part, we're flipping $3$ coins so $\mathsf P(2\text{ heads}\mid A)=3\cdot0.7^2\cdot0.3$

Comment: +1 Woops; misread that as flipping 2 coins. Fixed.